# Импорт сертификатов .crt, .pfx

Tags: ubuntu

Как выполнить импорт сертификатов .crt, .pfx на Ubuntu 18.04? При нажатии на сертификаты, открывается окно с описанием сертификата, но кнопка импорта неактивна. Есть какие-то другие способы?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/649463/457538, https://askubuntu.com/a/94861/457538 ?

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация. Суммарно убил уже около 7 часов, но результата так и нет.
Кто-нибудь смог решить?